# Server not working on any port except process.env.PORT?

Tags: node.js, express

How can i find the server port number ?

I have following code in server

```
var app = require('express')();
//creating http server
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var port = process.env.PORT;
server.listen(port);

app.get('/testUrl', function (req, res) {

console.log(server.address());
console.log(server.address().address);
console.log(server.address().port);

res.end("working " + port);
});
```

I want to know the port number where node server is running (added consoles in request) I am getting following information using consoles at request

\.\pipe\5e2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
undefined
undefined

Server returns following error If I change the server listening port to any other port except process.env.PORT

**iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.**

```
HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1001
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
```

Comment: is your port shown when you do console.log(port);

Comment: Yes,  It is looks like \.\pipe\5e2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: What's the problem? It's unix domain socket

Comment: I need to use this server for socket.io, How can i call server from client side without port number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in code , your are not defining default port.for set your default port you have to do like this.

```
var port = process.env.PORT || '';//put your default port here in ''.
```

and set your PORT in env

```
export PORT="your port number"(in terminal)
```

Comment: still server.address() returns port as \\.\pipe\ae6fc53d-7c5f-4d04-9041-4cfb6e613f6c

Comment: can you do var port = 122;//set your port no here